# Validate jQuery plugin not working with Dialog Modal

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to implement some form validation with jQuery plugin [Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) but cant get to work. The form is called from

```
<!-- Div for Add Row Modal Box  -->
   <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
      <p class="validateTips">Some form fields (*) are required.</p>

     <form id="addForm" title="Add New Record">&nbsp;<br/>
       <fieldset>
        <label for="fname">First Name:</label><input type="text" id ="fname" name="FName_val" maxlength="12" size="12"  placeholder="*" required class="input_style" rel="0" /><br /><br />
        <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><input type="text" id ="lname" name="LName_val" maxlength="45" size="12" placeholder="*" required class="input_style" rel="1" /><br /><br />
        <label for="etype">Equipment Type:</label><input type="text" id ="etype" name="Equipment_Borrowed_val" maxlength="50" placeholder="*" required size="14" class="input_style" rel="2" /><br /><br />
        <label for="stag">Service Tag:</label><input type="text" id ="stag" name="Service_Tag_val" maxlength="6" size="6"  class="input_style" rel="3"/><br />
        <label for="input_select"><br />
         Equipment Status:</label> <select name="Borrwd_Rsn_val" id="input_select" rel="4">
               <option value="Borrowed" selected="selected">Borrowed</option>
               <option value="In for Repair">In for Repair</option>
               <option value="Replacement" >Replacement</option>
               <option value="Returned" >Returned</option>
               <option value="Other">Other</option>
             </select>
         <br />
         <br />
         <label for="dtaken">Date Taken:</label><input type="text" id ="dtaken" name="Date_Taken_val" autocomplete="on" placeholder="dd/mm/yy" class="input_style" rel="5"/><br /><br />

         <label for="ereturn">Expected<br/>Return Date:</label><input type="text" id ="ereturn" name="Exp_Date_Return_val" placeholder="dd/mm/yy" autocomplete="on" class="input_style" rel="6" /><br />
          <br />
          <br/>
         <label for="comments"></label><textarea id ="comments" name="Comments_val" placeholder="Add Comments Here" maxlength="255" cols="40" rows="4"  wrap=HARD class="input_style" rel="7"></textarea>
          <br />
          <br />
        </fieldset>
       </form>
    </div> 
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

     $(function() {
      $("#addForm").validate();
     });
 });

   </script>
```

and then I would like it validate once I press the "add row" button from the jQuery dialog button:

```
buttons: {
         "Add a Row": function() {
             var dTable = $('#the_table').DataTable();
             //Use DataTables API row.add() method to add row client-side
             dTable.row.add([
                $('#fname').val(),
                $('#lname').val(),
                $('#etype').val(), 
                $('#stag').val(),
                $('#input_select').val(),
                $('#dtaken').val(),
                $('#ereturn').val(),
                $('#comments').val()       
              ]).draw();

              //Ajax for server-side portion of the add row

              var form = $( "#addForm" );
              form.validate();
              alert( "Valid: " + form.valid() );

              if(form.valid()) {
                //ajax here

               $.ajax({
                  url: "addData.php",
                  method: "POST",
                  data: { FName_val :  $('#fname').val(),
                          LName_val :  $('#lname').val(),
                          Equipment_Borrowed_val : $('#etype').val(),
                          Service_Tag_val : $('#stag').val(),
                          Borrwd_Rsn_val : $('#input_select').val(),
                          Date_Taken_val : $('#dtaken').val(),
                          Exp_Date_Return_val :  $('#ereturn').val(),
                          Comments_val :  $('#comments').val() 
                         },
                  success: function(result){
                   }     
                });
               dialog.dialog( "close" );
             }
            },
```

From reading documentation and examples I should get a warning once I click in and out of First name field without entering anything that says a minimum of two characters is required even without the code in the Dialog button to handle the submit. I get nothing and no errors in the console. Can someone see what I might be missing on how to implement this validation in the absence of a submit button in the form. Thanks...

Update: Corrected code per suggestion still no good.

Comment: don't know if this is just a typo but $("#addForm".validate(); is missing the closing ), should be $("#addForm").validate();

Comment: You are correct. Corrected to "$("#addForm").validate(); " and now get Typeerror:(..).validate is not a function in the console???

Comment: Are you including the library and calling it after the document is ready?

Comment: yes I'm using the cdn. here is link to pastebin with all code:http://pastebin.com/CjFavMu1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you need to call .valid() 
http://jsfiddle.net/ar4m2q9s/8/

http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

```
buttons: {
         "Add a Row": function() {
            var form = $( "#addForm" );
            form.validate();
            var isValid = form.valid();
            console.log("Page Valid: " + isValid)

            if(isValid)
            {
               //all other button code here.
            }

}
```

Comment: See corrected code above. What i get is modal dialog  stays up and no validation occurs and rows are just added client side but not server side? Any ideas.Thanks

Comment: Try wrapping the whole button function in the if()

Comment: Then I get uncaught type error.$(..).(validate) is not a function line 360.

Comment: Remove the script since we are calling validate again.

Comment: Sorry still get dialog with no validation and it stays up till cancelled. http://pastebin.com/CjFavMu1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87919/discussion-between-stephen-king-and-alan).